# custom setting issue in salesforce after installing managed package in developer account

Tags: salesforce

I'm really stucked at my final stage of coding. I've created a custom button in lead section and i'm calling custom setting url in javascript code.
    It works very well in my developer organization but it fails when I installs this in other developer organization.
    Here is the code for your reference;

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")}  
var uname = encodeURI('{!$Setup.UserDetails__c.UName__c}');   
var ukey= encodeURI('{!$Setup.UserDetails__c.Sha1Key__c}');  
try{  
var rurl= escape('/handleapprequest?email={!Lead.Email}&fname ={!Lead.FirstName}&lastname={!Lead.LastName}&company={!Lead.Company}');  
window.open('{!$Setup.UserDetails__c.Url__c}login/' + uname + '/'+ ukey +'?returnurl='+rurl, 'Send Email',   'height=600,location=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=1', 1)
}catch(err)  
{alert(err);}
```

When I install my package to different developer organization, the button which executes onClick javascript, thows an exception 'A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered: Field Setup.UserDetails_*c.UName*_c does not exists check spelling'
    Please, let me know what is going wrong here? I've already created Beta package and I can not change or remove code from my developer org.
    Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should check whether you actually included the Custom Setting in your package.  If you don't do that then it just won't exist in the new org.

Even if you do have the Custom Setting in the package, you still have to put a value in it in the destination org.  Packages include metadata only, not data, and so you'll have to add a row to this custom setting for your button to pick it up.  You can do this manually in the destination org, or you can do it automatically with a post-install trigger.  Even if you've got a beta managed package, you can still add objects and code to it, by the way.